# PostgreSQL: The ereport function does not clear the stack before exiting

Tags: c, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I'm just trying to exit the function with an error, however the stack is not cleared.
I wrote a Foo class and create logs in the destructor. However, nothing is logged

```
#pragma once

#include "Logger.h"
inline auto& logger = Logger::getInstance();

extern "C"
{

#include "postgres.h"
#include "fmgr.h"

#include "miscadmin.h"
#include "catalog/pg_authid.h"
#include "utils/syscache.h"
#include "utils/builtins.h"

PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(simpleFuntions);
Datum simpleFuntions(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS);

}
```

test.cpp

```
#include "test.h"

extern "C"
{
    PG_MODULE_MAGIC;
}
class Foo
{
    public:
    Foo(){logger.log("START");};
    ~Foo(){logger.log("TEST IS CORRECT!");};
};

Datum simpleFuntions(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
        Foo che;
        ereport(ERROR,
            (
                errcode(ERRCODE_NULL_VALUE_NOT_ALLOWED),
                errmsg("ERROR")
            )
        );
 
        FlushErrorState();
    
    PG_RETURN_TEXT_P(cstring_to_text("HelloWorld"));
}
```

After function execution, in logs file I see only "START".

Comment: Are you aware that Postgres 9.2 is no longer maintained? Even if there is such a bug, it won't be fixed in that outdated version.

Comment: Yep, I know it. I write that code for many versions. But 9.2 is first

Comment: `ereport(ERROR,
        (
            errcode(err_code),
            errmsg(error_msg) 
        )
    );` I got the feeling you have an extra set of `()` parentheses here. Resulting in two arguments to the function, the second being a parenthesised comma-operator - expression

Comment: @wildplasser I think my version is correct. I saw that function in documentation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/error-message-reporting.html

Comment: Time to check the sources. BRB

Comment: All error-info is collected in a (per-session) global `ErrorData` structure. The ereport() function just grabs info from this struct and formats/displays it. There must be functions to clear/reset this session-static data., possibly `FlushErrorState()` and/or `FreeErrorData()`

Comment: The sample code you show should work fine. Did you try it? Perhaps you should show something closer to your real code.

Comment: @wildplasser those functions "Delete all data in ErrorContext", but the variables from the stack are not stored there, as far as I understood. Therefore, these functions do not work for my task.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe yep, I added my full code to question. It's logging only "START". Logger is a static object.

Comment: Do you *really* need the PG_TRY/PG_CATCH/... mechanism (it uses siglongjump, this could interfere with critical sections).

Comment: @wildplasser this is optional. I just tried a new way to solve my problem. Now, I focus on basic ereport without try,catch constructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found a problem.
The fact is that postgres creates longjmp points. Therefore, when an ereport occurs, it returns the stack to the longjump point. Because of this, destructors are not called.
I solved this problem by lowering the level of my C++ code and wrapped it in try, catch. And already from the try, catch output I call ereport.
Also, I tried to solve my problem using override new operator with palloc function. But it doesn't work like I want.
https://habr.com/ru/post/442058/
There is probably no other solution

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-c.html#EXTEND-CPP) says:

All functions accessed by the backend must present a C interface to the backend; these C functions can then call C++ functions. **For example, `extern C` linkage is required for backend-accessed functions.**

Comment: The fact is that regardless of where they are called, the stack is not cleared. As I understand it, ereport clears the memory that was allocated free, and forgets about the stack.
If I change raise to ereport, the same thing happens.